# in Python 3, after encode('utf-8'), variable length changes from 2 to 4

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, encode

I am converting Python 2 codes to Python 3, and need to convert str to bytes using encode().

let the str variable's name s1.

set the unicode using `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the benigning of the *.py file.

in Python 2: type(s1)=`<type 'str'>`, len(s1)=2;

in Python 3: type(s1)=`<class 'str'>`, len(s1)=2; type(s1.encode())=`<class 'bytes'>`, but len(s1.encode())=4.

This length-change cause an error at:`unpack('H', s1.encode())`, error: *unpack requires a buffer of 2 bytes*

Comment: What is the content of `s1`?  Python 3 `str` and Python 2 `str` are not the same.  In Python 2 `str` is equivalent to Python 3 `bytes`.  In Python 3 `str` is equivalent to Python 2 `unicode`.

Comment: in Python 2.7 if print s1, gives �. unpack('H', s1) gives 131

Comment: What does `print repr(s1)` contain?  Please update the question with a [mcve] that reproduces the output you are reporting.

Comment: Length of a Unicode string it is calculated as UCS2 in python2 (so 2 chars for code points not in basic plane), as code point in python3 (so as UTF-32), Note This is not the real internal length. UTF-8 convert a string to byte, so you are counting the bytes. A character (code point)  can be 1, 2, 3 or 4 bytes in UTF-8.